# alias parameter doesn't expand as expected by bash

Tags: bash, alias

I'm reading the *LinuxShellScriptingCookbookThirdEdition* and practicing the code example from the book.
The book gave the following command to replace **rm** with a back-up version.

```
alias rm='cp $@ ~/backup && rm $@'
```

however, when i put this line into my **.bashrc**  and source it, the output after i ran **rm** was:

```
$ rm mail.txt    
cp: missing destination file operand after '/home/qiaozhuoyue/backup'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

which seems like **$@** was not expand as expected, then I used **echo "cp $@ ~/backup && rm $@"** instead, from the output I found that the position of the first **$@** was blank, that is, the former didn't expand as expected.

```
$ rm mail.txt
cp  ~/backup && rm  mail.txt
```

what I expect output is:

```
$ rm mail.txt
cp mail.txt ~/backup && rm  mail.txt
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: `$@` expands to shell's positional parameters, aliases don't take arguments.

Comment: Wow, that really is [straight out of the book](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/networking_and_servers/9781785881985/1/ch01lvl1sec16/visiting-aliases), and it doesn't work at all. I suddenly don't think much of this book. BTW, in addition to replacing it with a function (which *can* process arguments), you should also double-quote `"$@"` to avoid parsing weirdness.